# SVG polygon renders in Three.js, but can't find it in the SVGRenderer()

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I'm testing svg elements in Three.js.
I've added SVG elements in Three.js using SVGObject() where
SVGRenderer() creates a root svg element.

Two (2) SVG elements are added: polygon symbol and circle.
The circle is shown in the root svg element
Although the polygon symbol renders, I don't know where it's hiding.
It's not shown in the svg root element.
Where is it??

Here is the file in question:[Add SVG to Three.js](http://svgDiscovery.com/THREEjs/StackOverflow/three.js-SVG.htm)

Comment: Should be in `renderer.domElement.childNodes` and `renderer.domElement.children` [test](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/bmbjyLp7/)

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks for the try, mate. But 'tux' doesn't show up in the the renderer.domElement.innerHTML. I can only guess, at this moment, that anything included via SVGLoader() is located in some other location in three.js.

Comment: [renderer.domElement.childNodes](http://i.imgur.com/Qc37LmS.png) Why didn't you mention in your question that you want it specifically from `.innerHTML`?